# Leer bit a bit de un fichero binario

Tags: php

Quiero leer de un archivo binario (transport stream MPEG-2) los diferentes valores bit a bit. 
Un pedazo de mi código es:

```
    $fp = fopen($file, 'rb');
    while (!feof($fp)){
        $tsbits = 188;
        $data = fread($fp, $tsbits);
        $arr = unpack("H*", $data);
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
            echo ' ' . $value;
        }
        echo "<br>";
    }
```

$tsbits = 188 debido a la longitud que tiene un transport stream.

De esta manera, ahora mismo el primer bit que se muestra en pantalla es 47, pero me gustaría que se visualizase como 0x47.
¿Cómo sería la manera correcta?

Answer (score 0):

si no interpreto mal lo que intentas hacer es leer un archivo y mostrarlo en formato HEX, para ello necesitas realizar los siguientes pasos.

1. Leer/cargar el archivo con la función fopen().
2. Pasar el archivo a un formato que puedas manipular con la función fread().
3. Operar con los datos que cargaste.

Estas son unas aclaraciones de como se usan las funciones antes mencionadas:

```
//file seria la ubicación junto al nombre y extensión del archivo, length el tamaño del archivo.
fread(file, length)
filesize(file)
```

Solo tendrías que cambiar la salida para mostrarlo con un formato HEX

```
$fp = fopen($file, 'rb');
while (!feof($fp)){
    $tsbits = 188; //CUIDADO solo mostrara los primeros 188 chrs
    $data = fread($fp, $tsbits);
    $arr = unpack("H*", $data);
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
        echo ' 0x' . $value;
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: El caso es que fread  lee en bytes, y mi intención es leer en bits. ¿Se podría hacer? Por que si modifico el valor de $tsbits =1, esto equivale a que fread leerá 1 byte, no 188.

Comment: Creo que no entiendes el concepto de lo que estas haciendo, cada carácter es un byte que equivale a 8 bits. Por norma general los bytes se manipulan en hex y los bits en binario, pero los archivos binarios que se llama coloquial mente hacen referencia a los caracteres del 0x00 al 0xFF de la tabla ascii.

Resumiendo: 23 bytes equivalen a 184 o 24 bytes equivalen a 192 bits, no puedes leer 188 bits de un archivo, tiene que ser múltiplo de 8.